# Why codeigniter etc disallow get variables

Tags: php, http, codeigniter

Why is it that codeigniter and perhaps other mvc frameworks disallow the use of get variables.  Is it security? DO they think that get is overused and abused?

I think that both post and get have their places and should be used for their intended uses?

Can anyone offer an explanation for me?

Comment: What do you mean by "disallow the use of get variables"?  Do you mean the `$_GET` array?

Answer (score 3):

### Update:

Here is the answer from CI:

> Destroys the global GET array. Since CodeIgniter does not utilize GET
> strings, there is no reason to allow
> it.
>
> Destroys all global variables in the event register_globals is turned on.
>
> Filters the POST/COOKIE array keys, permitting only alpha-numeric (and a
> few other) characters.

Source: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

They most likely replace it for security reasons (although not sure) or in favor of their input library which allows you to prevent XSS attacks amongst other things.

You can still access GET and POST data through the input library like this:

```
$var = $this->input->post('varname', true);
$var = $this->input->get('varname', true);
```

The `true` argument is whether or not you want to run XSS filter function on your variables/data.